# How to approach mathematical modeling of the human heart problem?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

I have to create a mathematical model of the human heart but it was quite a time ago I finished University and I experience some difficulties with the math behind the subject.

What is the necessary level in mathematics to complete the task?
What is the best starting point in mathematical modeling?
What areas in mathematical analysis are needed to allow me to accomplish the project?
Are there some introductory material easy to follow and understand to approach the problem?

Comment: It's really impossible to say without knowing how much detail you want to model (just beating with a few degrees of freedom? treat muscle tissue as continuous? model individual cells? or organelles? or molecules? how about blood supply so you can model infarctions? are you modeling the pericardial fluid too? or what about inputs for blood pressure regulation?) .... however, in general some backing in ordinary differential equations and numerical methods for solving same will probably be a miniumum.

Comment: You might want to see [this](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/handbooks/15708659/12).

Comment: @Henning Makholm. I presume I have to start with Hodgkin-Huxley model first. I've also read about monodomain, bidoman and reaction-diffusion models currently in use. I'm not sure about the detail yet. I need a model to allow simulation of a e.g. PAF onset during the the normal heart rythm

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_plot This Wikipedia article is quite stubby, but may nonetheless be of interest.  Also see this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heart_rate_variability and this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinus_rhythm

Comment: Here's fairly long list of time-series topics; which ones are relevant will take some work to answer: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Time_series_analysis

Comment: @Michael. Thank you for the links. I'm quite versed in time series analysis and physiology as you can see from my academic page. I miss mathematical background to allow me to develop 3D mathematical model of the realistic heart signal

Comment: @ChesnokovYuriy Have you already checked "Mathematical Physiology" by Keener & Sneyd? It includes chapters on the human heart (Chapter 12) and can be a good starting point.

Comment: @pharmine thank you for the link. I've got some books on heart physiology and modeling with many differential and integral equations. I presume I'd rather need some introductory material on these, how to create and solve them